# How to use Flask to route with a React app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm a React developer who's new to Flask. I'd like to route in backend with Flask and build frontend with React. My first scaffold looks like this:

Folder structure:

```
react-flask-app
 -api
   -app.py
 -public
   -index.html
 -src
   -pages
     -Home.js
     -Page1.js
   -components
     -Navbar.js
   -App.js
```

App.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('../public/index.html')
```

Navbar.js:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <a href='/'>Home</a>
            <a href='/page1'>Page 1</a>
        </>
    )
};
```

Home.js:

```
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <div>Homepage</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Page1.js

```
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const Page1 = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar />
            <div>Page 1</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

When I run the React app, I can switch between `http://localhost:3000/` and `http://localhost:3000/page1` by clicking the Navbar buttons, but it does not display Page1, since I've not set routing yet.

My question is, I know Flask can be used for routing, how can I use Flask to route and link to each page in this case?

Comment: React is for creating Single Page Application. All the page should be requested through ajax call. You can do this through babel.js.

Answer (score 0):

To tell react to proxy any requests to Flask, add a `proxy` field to your `package.json`, e.g

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Then use `ajax`, `fetch` from within your components to access your API.

More Information can be found in [Proxying in development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)